# why does this version of xslt 2.0 identity transform not work?

Tags: xslt

Why does this not also copy all the nodes in the document, like the xslt identity transform?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Why does the template have to match `@* | node()` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *identity transform* template works **recursively**. When it calls:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
```

it applies **itself** (unless another template with a higher priority exist) to the child attributes and nodes of the current node.

Your version matches and processes only the `/` root node. When it calls for templates to be applied to the children, the processor will look for templates that match these - and your template will not be among them.

Comment: And it outputs the text nodes of the entire document because it uses the default templates on all the other nodes?